How to add secret to Background Gen2 Cloud functions
In gen 1 http request we have
functions.
    runWith({secrets: ["WA_TOKEN"]})
    .https.onRequest

and gen2 http request
    exports.processPayment = onRequest(
  { secrets: ["SECRET_NAME"] },
  (req, res) => {
    const myBillingService = initializeBillingService(
      // reference the secret value
      process.env.SECRET_NAME
    );
    // Process the payment
  }
);

What is the equivalent to this with gen 2 background cloud function say example
exports.myfunction = onDocumentWritten("users/marie", (event) => {
  // Your code here
});

How is this not documented I have used the secret before in background gen1 functions like
exports.onUserChange = functions.
    runWith({secrets: ["TWILIO_SID"]}).firestore
    .document("Users/{userId}")
    .onUpdate( async (change, context) => {

But somehow for gen2 functions it is not said how to do this.
How is this done

Have you checked this documentation on configuring secrets for Cloud Functions Gen 2?

I need it as code, the background functions have two params and none specifies 'secrets'. Just like the examples I have given
